# Importing Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
english_list = ["fire","apple","morning","river","wind"]
spanish_list = ["fuego","manzana","mañana","río","viento"]
english_to_spanish = dict(zip(english_list, spanish_list))
spanish_to_english = dict(zip(spanish_list, english_list))

def translate(word):
    translation = english_to_spanish.get(word)
    if translation:
        return translation

    translation = spanish_to_english.get(word)
    if translation:
        return translation

    raise Exception('Word {0} does not exists'.format(word))

print("Welcome to the English <--> Spanish Dictionary")
while True:
    word = input("> ")
    if word == 'show':
        wordlist = input("Would you like to see the English or Spanish wordlist?")
        if wordlist == 'english':
            print(english_list)
        elif wordlist == 'spanish':
            print(spanish_list)
    else:
        try:
            print(translate(word))
        except Exception as exeception:
            print ("That wasn't a option")
```

this is my code, i would like to import a dictionary(which i have)but i am not sure how to do this, i am quite new to coding and really need some help, this is a school assignment and i really need seaminess help, any help would be massively appreciated!!

Comment: What is the *format* of the dictionary you want to import?

Comment: By import, do you mean that you have a file with word pairs (English paired with Spanish)? OR as is implied by your example, that you have two separate files with lists of English words and Spanish words?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import your dictionary from a json file, you can do like this

```
import json

json_path = 'your_json_file.json'
with open(json_path) as json_data:
    your_dictionary = json.load(json_data)
```